# How is the last step of this sum derived?

Tags: summation, exponential-sum

From the book [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html) page 108

[image]

In the final sum I can see where the $0.1$ in front and the $0.9^k$ in the sum come from, but I can't see how the $2^k$ and 2 come from the part above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$-th term in the sum corresponds to the length $k+1$ episode.

Remark that in the length $k+1$ episode the $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{0.5}$ factors both appear $k+1$ times. Therefore, the $k$-th term in the sum contains the following multiplicative factor:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1} \cdot \left(2^{k+1}\right)^2 &= \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \cdot 2^{2(k+1)}\\
&= \frac{2^{2(k+1)}}{2^{k+1}}\\
&= 2^{2(k+1)-(k+1)}\\
&= 2^{k+1}\\
&= 2^k \cdot 2
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It comes from, for example $k=2$,

$$\frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 \left(\frac{1}{0.5}\frac{1}{0.5}\frac{1}{0.5}\right)^2 = 2^3 = 2^2 \cdot 2$$

And, then, in general,

$$\left(\frac 12 \right)^{k+1} \left[\left(\frac{1}{0.5}\right)^{k+1}\right]^2  = 
\frac 12 \left(\frac 12 \right)^k 2^{2k+2}= 2^k \cdot 2$$

Answer (score 1):

'twere up to me I wouldn't skip steps.

The summation seems to be: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac 12)^k*(0.9)^{k-1}*(0.1)*([\frac 1{0.5}]^k)^2$

Now $\frac 1{0.5} = 2$ so that is

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac 12)^k*(0.9)^{k-1}*(0.1)*2^{2k}$

And $(\frac 12)^k*2^{2k} = 2^k$.

so that is

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (0.9)^{k-1}*(0.1)*2^{k}$

Now we can put the $0.1$ constant in front

$0.1 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(0.9)^{k-1}*2^{k}$

Reindex from $0$

$0.1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(0.9)^{k}*2^{k+1}=$

$0.1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(0.9)^{k}*2^{k}*2$.

And we can combine the $(0.9)^k*2^{k}$ to get $1.8^k$ and bring the constant $2$ in front.

$0.2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1.8)^k$.

....

it's bit strange what other people consider easy to do in ones head.

Comment: yeah, I figured it had something to do with the exponential and the 1/2 but I didn't know that the 1/2 and 2 exponent cancelled out like that. Thanks